# Upload images into public folder within two frontend applications

Tags: next.js, file-upload

I'm building a project which has 3 applications: **server (nest.js)**, **admin (next.js)**, **client (next.js)**.

Currently I'm adding a feature into **admin** so him (or moderator) to be able to create a product which requires image, this part is happening in **admin** application f.e. within the route `./admin/src/app/products/[productId]/create`

I decided I will be storing images which relate to the **client** in the `public/` folder on the **client** in order not to send **base64** string or whatever else between **server** and **client**.

Want to know if it has any sense to do so. Following this scheme I'll store in the database a path to the image instead of image itself which will save me a lot of space as well as make requests lighter

On of the approaches is to save images via `next.js api` f.e. and send multipart/formdata but here **question** appears if it's possible to save images within different applications?